# Check whether 2 trees have same inorder or not

Tags: c++, tree

I was solving this problem using 1 array but while traversing the second tree am always getting false as an answer. Couldnt able to understand where to put the true condition . I could have solved it using queue also by checking the front element and checking whether the queue is empty at the end or not but i would like to use this approach for now . By the first inorder func i am filling my vector with inorder traversal of tree1 and by the inorder function with has 3 arguments i am checking whether the inorder at every index of tree1 is same as tree2 or not.

```
class TreeNode
{
public:
    int data;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;

    TreeNode(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};




void inorder(TreeNode *root , vector<int>&v)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    inorder(root->left, v);
    v.push_back(root->data);
    inorder(root->right, v);
}

bool inorder(TreeNode * tree2 , vector<int> v , int index)
{

    if (tree2)
    {
        bool l =   inorder(tree2->left , v , index);
        if (index == v.size() || tree2->data != v[index++])
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool r =  inorder(tree2->right , v, index);

        return r && l;

    }
}






int main()
{

#ifndef YOLO
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);
#endif


    TreeNode* tree1 = new TreeNode(5);
    tree1->left = new TreeNode(3);
    tree1->left->left = new TreeNode(1);
    tree1->right = new TreeNode(7);
    tree1->right->left = new TreeNode(6);

    TreeNode* tree2 = new TreeNode(3);
    tree2->left = new TreeNode(1);
    tree2->right = new TreeNode(6);
    tree2->right->left = new TreeNode(5);
    tree2->right->right = new TreeNode(7);
    vector<int>v;
    inorder(tree1, v);

    //cout << v.size();
    cout << inorder(tree2, v, 0);
}
```

Comment: can you explain what the function `inorder` is supposed to do? I don't understand why it uses only one tree and why it takes an empty vector by value

Comment: i editted the questioin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't understand why you are doing it this way. A simpler method would be to create a second vector from the second tree and compare the vectors.

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<int> v2;
inorder(tree1,v1);
inorder(tree2,v2);
if(v1==v2)
    std::cout<<"the same\n";
else
    std::cout<<"not the same\n";
```

EDIT: if you insist on this method then the below function works (idx is a global variable)

```
 int idx = 0;
    bool check(Node* t, std::vector<int>& v) {
        if (t == nullptr) return true;
        bool la = check(t->left, v);
        if (t->data != v[idx])return false;
        else ++idx;
        bool ra = check(t->right, v);
        return la && ra;
    }
```

Comment: thats the first thing i did but i want to solve it using a single array only

Comment: @KrishanKumar ok in that case check the edit it contains working code

Comment: why you returning true when t==null. Like in case out tree 1 has values in vector but tree2 has none in that case too it will going to return true .can you please explain

Comment: @KrishanKumar well the code assumes that each tree has at least one node. It is easy to check before calling the function that it contains at least one node. If it doesn't then tree2=nullptr